# DbVisualizer :Cannot connect to ORB

Tags: oracle, dbvisualizer

Please refer below error !!I am not able to add connections to database.I searched other answers but they aren't helpful.

```
Product:  DbVisualizer Free 6.5.4
Build:  #1362 (2009/02/05 20:09)
Java VM:  Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
Java Version:  1.8.0_25
Java Vendor:  Oracle Corporation
OS Name:  Windows XP
OS Arch:  x86
OS Version:  5.1

An error occurred while establishing the connection:
   Type: javax.naming.CommunicationException
Message:
   Cannot connect to ORB
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DbVisualizer 6.5.4 is very old and you should upgrade to the latest [9.2.13](http://www.dbvis.com/download/). It comes with the Oracle driver bundled and connecting is easy without needing to setup the driver.

Comment: Very Helpful !! Althaugh i dont have sufficient privilages to install new version.. i somehow installed it.. feeling awsome..thankss :)